# Motion of a cube dropped at an angle

Tags: collision, rotation, rigid-body-dynamics

Let's say we have a cube with a mass *m* being held a distance *d* from the ground. Also, the cube is being held at an angle such that when it collides with the ground, it tumbles around a bit before coming to a complete stop. At *t = 0* seconds, the cube is dropped, and the force of gravity causes the cube to fall. The questions is, given a specific point in time, how could we calculate the position and orientation of the cube after colliding with the ground? Are there any major mathematical models that could come into play in this scenario? I'm trying to create a rigid body system for a game engine, but I can't find any good resources on this topic.

Comment: There's some sort of contradiction: you *ignore* air friction, but you are expecting that the cube will stop? how?

Comment: My question might not have been clear enough, but I meant the box coming to a stop because of gravity. The box should roll around a bit like a die, and then come to rest on one of the faces. However, if air resistance / friction are crucial factors here, then feel free to utilize them in a response.

Comment: Ok just Google 'equations for rigid body collisions, regular poligons' , that might help

Answer (score 0):

This question may seem simple, but is not at all and is possibility chaotic in nature – i.e. a small deviation in starting orientation or height can lead to a vastly different final trajectory.

Modeling a falling, tumbling cube is simple enough. Choose an initial position, orientation, center-of-mass velocity and rotation vector, and you can calculate the position of any point on the cube in a straightforward way using the rigid body equations of motion.

Once it strikes the ground, however, you have to make additional assumptions.  Is it a perfectly elastic collision, where no energy is lost? In this case your die will behave like a cubic superball, and keep bouncing indefinitely. The trajectory it takes will be highly dependent on exactly where it hits and how the impact redirects its rotation.
If you want to get a little closer to reality, you might make the collision partly inelastic, assigning a coefficient of restitution to each bounce.

Because of the (I'm guessing) chaotic nature of this system, there is no simple mathematical formula to capture all its possible trajectories, like you might have for a sphere bouncing.  So you will have no better option than to start with the dynamic equations of motion and use software to numerically map out the trajectory for a given starting condition.

At this point, you would be better off running a test.  You could get a real die and track its motion by video, and try to learn some things about it. With modern smartphones you can almost certainly do this by getting an app that can analyze videos and track moving objects, even plotting the x-y trajectory perhaps.  I encourage you to try this. It would not be hard to build a mounting device that allows you to preset the height and orientation of the die before releasing it. In physics we often learn best by doing, and experiments like this you can build in your garage can be invaluable in gaining insticts and insight into physical behavior of systems.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I'm considering trying the experiment in real life, but are you aware of any major (or minor) physics concepts that come into play here? It would be nice to be able to apply something to this problem.

Comment: Rigid body equations of motion. Elastic and inelastic collisions. Ballistic motion. These are things you can look up.